# Encrypting directories with gpg

Tags: encryption, gpg

I want to use GPG for local encryption only, and after reading the man file, I'm doing the following in order to encrypt a whole directory:

I zip the directory with a password "`zip -r -e foo foo`", then I encrypt it with "`gpg -c foo.zip`" using a passphrase. Is this an elegant and secure way of encrypting directories? Am I using GPG's full cryptographic power? Are there better alternatives?

So there's no a way to encrypt a whole directory without zip it or tar it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this an elegant and secure way of encrypting directories?

Elegant -- no.  Secure -- as secure as `gpg`.

> Am I using GPG's full cryptographic power?

Yes.

> Are there better alternatives?

`tar` the directory first instead of `zip`.  `gpg` compresses data anyway.

Comment: How can I do it without tar on zip the directory?

Comment: The point of running `zip` or `tar` before `gpg` is to assemble the entire directory in a single file, since `gpg` can't deal with several files at once (that is, it can encode them one by one, but not create a single archive of a directory; there are also efficiency reasons, but that's another story).  Now, the UNIX way of (reversibly) doing that is to use `tar`: it preserves owners, permissions, modification times etc.  There are other ways to do it, f.i. `cpio`.  But `tar` works fine, and it's by far the most the most widely used.  There are no advantages in using anything else.

Answer (score 5):

GPG itself acts on one file at a time. Acting on directories is not its job. Packing directories into single objects is the job of an archiver. Thus it is perfectly natural to create an archive (e.g. with `tar`) and call `gnupg` on it if you want to encrypt it. Alternatively, you can encrypt each file individually. If you're only worried about file contents, these two methods are equivalent. If you also want to hide file names, size breakdown and so on, only encrypting an archive helps.

Some applications, including Emacs and Vim, can transparently edit files encrypted with GPG; they'll just prompt you for your passphrase when needed.

It is also possible to write a stackable filesystem, i.e. a filesystem that stores files as encrypted files on another filesystem. The way to build stackable filesystems is with [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). There is at least one FUSE filesystem that uses GPG for storage, [GPGFS](https://github.com/jseppanen/gpgfs). I've never used it and cannot vouch for its quality. There is also [Encfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS), also based on FUSE, which doesn't use gpg but uses a similar principle.

[Ecryptfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs) is another filesystem for Linux that stores files as encrypted files on another filesystems. It's what Ubuntu uses for encrypted home directories. It's targeted at encrypting your whole home directory rather than one specific directory.